# Grails Doc Engine: What is the syntax for insertions?

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I am trying to use [insertions](http://redcloth.org/textile/phrase-modifiers/#insertions-and-deletions) in my documentation using `Grails 2.4.4`. According to the Textile syntax this should be

```
+Text with insertion+
```

The output of the Grails Documentation Engine is +Text with insertion+.

Can anyone tell me whats the syntax of insertions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not supported. Note that Grails doc files use a markup that's inspired by Textile, but is not textile; it's described in the docs as "a variation on the Textile syntax"

Comment: Thank you Burt. Would it be possible to extend this functionality? I'd love to provide a pull request but need some coordinates of the Grails module that implements the doc engine. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-docs/src/main/groovy/grails/doc/DocEngine.groovy

Comment: Yep, that's it - is uses the now defunct "radeox" library. Before you do much work extending this, send an email to the dev forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss) about future plans. Asciidoc is generating a lot of buzz lately and it seems like a great option for Grails 3.0, so perhaps working on a plugin for 2.x that could become the standard doc engine for 3.0 would be a better way forward.